# How to use type inference so that possible immutable/const is removed?

Tags: d

How can I use type inference to remove immutable/const in a variable declaration? Is that possible at all?

```
immutable uint immutableX = 42;
// keep the type (uint) but remove the immutability
/* compiler magic */ mutableX = immutableX;
```

The non type inference solution is:

```
uint mutableX = immutableX;
```

A full example:

```
void main()
{
    immutable uint immutableX = 42;
    pragma(msg, "immutableX: ", typeof(immutableX));
    assert(typeof(immutableX).stringof == "immutable(uint)");

    // how to use type inference so that possible immutable/const is removed ?
    // the expected type of mutableX is uint
    auto mutableX = immutableX;
    pragma(msg, "mutableX: ", typeof(immutableX));
    // this should be true
    assert(typeof(immutableX).stringof == "uint");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on use case, there's [`std.traits.Unqual`](https://dlang.org/library/std/traits/unqual.html), which removes the outermost `immutable`, `const`, `shared`, etc:

```
import std.traits : Unqual;
immutable int a = 3;
Unqual!(typeof(a)) b = a;
static assert(is(typeof(b) == int));
```

An easier solution might be `cast()`:

```
immutable int a = 3;
auto b = cast()a;
static assert(is(typeof(b) == int));
```

Which is correct depends on where and how you will use it.